# How to faster map density matrix element to make differential equations

Tags: matrix, tensors

I have a time dependent matrix $M(t)$ of $L^n \times L^n$ size and want to write differential equations like `D[M[i,j][t],t] = H[i,j][t]`

Here is my code:

```
L=3; n=3;
Rho[t_] = Table[M[i,j][t], {i,L^n}, {j,L^n}]; //Timing(*Rho2[t]//MatrixForm*)
(* {0.00100,Null} *)

Hop[t_, i_] =
    Transpose[
      Table[If[i == j, 1, Cos[t]], {i, {1}}, {j, L}]]
    . Table[If[i == j, 1, Sin[t]], {i, {2}}, {j, L}]

I1[i_Integer] := I1[i]=IdentityMatrix[L^(i-1)];
I2[i_Integer] := I2[i]=IdentityMatrix[L^(n-i)];

H[t_] = Sum[FixedPoint[ArrayFlatten, I1[i] \[TensorProduct] Hop[t,i] 
    \[TensorProduct]I2[i]],{i,n}];

Rho1[t_] =
    Table[
        D[Rho[t],t][[i,j]] == H[t][[i,j]],
        {i,L^n}, {j,L^n}]; // Timing(*Rho1[t]//MatrixForm*)
(* {0.33500,Null} *)
```

I can make it faster by using the `Parallel` command:

```
Rho2[t_] =
    ParallelTable[
        D[Rho[t],t][[i,j]] == H[t][[i,j]],
        {i,L^n}, {j,L^n}]; // Timing(*Rho1[t]//MatrixForm*)
(* {0.08100,Null} *)
```

Is there any other way by using `Map` or `Transpose` to make it more efficient?

Comment: In your formulation of `Rho1[t_]` you should be able to simply use `Map[D[#, t] &, Rho[t]]`. On my machine using `Table` gives a timing of 0.277257, while using `Map` gives a timing of 0.001321. Is this the operation you are trying to speed up? Maybe I misunderstood the question.

Comment: There's no need to `Table` in your `Rho1[t_] = ...`. `D` is [`Listable`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Listable.html) so you can just write `Rho1[t_] = D[Rho[t], t]`.

Comment: @Silvia right you are. I forgot about the `Listable` nature of `D[…]`. Your solution reads better.

Comment: @Silvia I made a mistake before, please look at the edited version. I want to make set of differential equations in this form `D[M[i,j][t],t]=H[i,j][t]`. @leibs Map make it good but still not that efficient because I need to create set of diff. equations.

Comment: Do you want your `Rho2` a matrix shape or a 1-dimension list with all equations is ok?

Comment: a list of all equations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Thread` to "thread" the `==` over the list:

```
Rho2[t_] = Thread /@ Thread[D[Rho[t], t] == H[t]];
```

Which is much more efficient than `Table` or `ParallelTable`.

The inner `Thread` map `{{..}, {..}, ..., {...}} == {{..}, {..}, ..., {..}}` to `{{..} == {..}, {..} == {..}, ..., {..} == {..}}`; the outer `Thread` perform on each `.. == ..` to make it `{{.. == .., ...}, {.. == .., ...}, ..., {.. == .., ...}}`.

Comment: Another way to look at it is to flatten the arrays first and then use `MapThread` such as `MapThread[Equal, {Flatten[D[Rho[t], t]], Flatten[H[t]]}]` The difference being that the above solution will produce an array of the same dimension as the original where as using the solution with `Flatten` will produce a list of equations.

Comment: @leibs Or `Thread[Flatten[D[Rho[t], t] - H[t]] == 0]`:) But `Flatten` can be a bit more time-consuming than two `Thread`.